# how to verify already pushed github commits

Tags: git, gnupg

How can I gpg-sign commits that I already pushed?
I tried `git filter-branch -f --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@"' HEAD` and it verified some commits and 'unverified' already verified commits like here: https://github.com/DeBos99/sudofix/commits/master

Comment: Verify your signatures locally: run [`git log --show-signature`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---show-signature).

Comment: Signature is the same everywhere (key, name, email etc.)

Comment: `git log --show-signature` verifies commits by passing the signature to `gpg --verify` and shows the output. The output (good or bad signature) may hints where is the problem.

Comment: And in every commit I have same signature and same information that signature is good etc.

Comment: Then all commits are signed. The problem with "unverified" commits is at Github side. Try to contact support.